Why is device_name in aws_volume_attachment mandatory?
I created an EC2 instance with a root volume and an additional volume. For the additional volume, I used aws_volume_attachment. This resource has an mandatory argument device_name, but it is not used.
Documentation


device_name - (Required) The device name to expose to the instance (for example, /dev/sdh or xvdh). See Device Naming on Linux Instances and Device Naming on Windows Instances for more information.


Terraform
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "my_volume" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdb"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.my_volume.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.my_instance.id
}

Console
ubuntu@my_instance:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
xvda    202:0    0    10G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    10G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    22G  0 disk 

Reasearch

I read Device name considerations:


Depending on the block device driver of the kernel, the device could be attached with a different name than you specified. For example, if you specify a device name of /dev/sdh, your device could be renamed /dev/xvdh or /dev/hdh. In most cases, the trailing letter remains the same. In some versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and its variants, such as CentOS), the trailing letter could change (/dev/sda could become /dev/xvde). In these cases, the trailing letter of each device name is incremented the same number of times. For example, if /dev/sdb is renamed /dev/xvdf, then /dev/sdc is renamed /dev/xvdg. Amazon Linux creates a symbolic link for the name you specified to the renamed device. Other operating systems could behave differently.


So the device name cannot set for every operating system. Therefore it is confusing when the value is set.

I read Attribute Reference:


device_name - The device name exposed to the instance


But the device name is still /dev/sdb instead of xvdb. So the value is wrong and not useful.


Question
Why is device_name mandatory if it is not used?

Note that it's required on the underlying AWS AttachVolume request.

@jarmod Thank you. Do you know, why it is required on the AWS API?

I don't know for sure. It does seem to be used indirectly and can presumably help users to infer the device name mapping. Perhaps it's historically been required because of the days when Xen hypervisor was the only game in town.
